# Applying validation on attribute in Hybris

Tags: java, spring, sap-commerce-cloud

I have created Pan attribute on registration page.  I have to apply validation for it like 1-5 digits will be alphabets, 6-9 will be numeric and tenth digit will be alphabet.

I tried logic for length of Pan no it worked
private void validatePan(final Errors errors, final String pan)
{

```
    if (StringUtils.isEmpty(pan))
    {
        errors.rejectValue("pan", "register.pan.invalid");
    }
    else if (StringUtils.length(pan) > 10 || StringUtils.length(pan) < 10)
    {
        errors.rejectValue("pan", "register.pan.invalid");
    }

}
```

Please provide the next part of validation as per requirement.

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex for single line of code like below:

```
final Pattern PATTERN_PAN = Pattern.compile("^[a-zA-Z]{5}[0-9]{4}[a-zA-Z]{1}$");
if (!PATTERN_PAN.matcher(pan).matches()) {
    errors.rejectValue("pan", "register.pan.invalid");
}
```